# Need to change data type of text area field to long text area

Tags: force.com

Need to change data type of text area field to long text area, is there any way we can deploy this change in PROD without commenting the code?

Comment: No, other than deploying the code and object change at the same time.

Comment: Thank you @caleb.breckon, I am not sure why but when I deployed this change to another sandbox, it deployed successfully without giving any error about related Apex Classes. However it throws error if I try to change field data type manually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways using the Force.com migration tool:

1. Take the entire code dependency in package and deploy it together.

If above approach doesn't work:-

2. Prepare destructve XML and add all dependent components in it. Same way all those dependent components in package.xml. Perform deployment together. Destructive XML should run first then package.xml but in same payload zip.